# Do psychiatrists have educational requirements other than an MD?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, psychiatry, medication

Most pre-medical students take psychology, biology, chemistry or something science-related, in addition to the classes needed as prerequisites for medical school, for their undergraduate degree or even for a master's, but is there any particular degree besides an MD that someone who wants to be a psychiatrist needs to take?

For example, is a business, philosophy, english or political science major who has taken the required classes of medical school who later finishes medical school eligible to train to become a psychiatrist? I'm curious as to how such a person would get the psychology-related training and knowledge. Is it in the training after medical school? Is it related to medical school electives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only required degree to become a psychiatrist is a doctoral degree (M.D.). Using your example, yes those people could train to become psychiatrists.

After passing the Medical College Admission Test (MCAT) and going through med school, most students undergo a psychiatric residency (aka. clerkship) where they are trained in different medical centers (hospitals, health clinics, psychiatric wards, etc.). This allows the prospective psychiatrist to gain "real world" experience. After a psychiatric residency, psychiatrists must then take an exam issued by the [American Board of Psychiatry and Neurology](http://www.abpn.com/). If they pass this exam they are certified and can then legally practice as a psychiatrist.

**Source:**  http://study.com/articles/Psychiatrist_Educational_Requirements_for_Psychiatrists.html

Edit: Med school teaches you theoretical psychiatric knowledge whereas the clerkship will teach you how to apply it. The clerkship could also train you in specialty fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Harris, but before one undergoes clerkship, does one have psychiatric knowledge in the med school necessarily?

Comment: @JackBauer Med school teaches you theoretical psychiatric knowledge whereas the clerkship will teach you how to apply it. The clerkship could also train you in specialty fields.

Comment: Include in answer?